# How to Create a Series of Webpages

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

By series of pages I mean having pages that can be navigated to using <kbd>Previous</kbd>, <kbd>Next</kbd>, or <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>...</kbd> The content being a list of 10 songs, and to see more the user can just click <kbd>Next</kbd>. I'm planning to use PHP and MySQL. I need your opinions on how to go about it (Not explicitly asking for code but personal opinions that may be supplemented with code). Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like /page/2... and so on?

Comment: So, a question about pagination?

Comment: Nowadays I prefer infinite scrolling over pagination.

Comment: Oh! So that's what they call it, Pagination. Thanks! @Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

MySQL offers the `LIMIT X,Y` keyword which does most of this work already. `X` is always the starting position and `Y` the amount of rows to select.

If you have, for example, a search form, and the user searches for a song of the genre *pop*, you could do something like `SELECT name, artist, ... FROM songs WHERE genre = 'pop' LIMIT 0,10`. This will return 10 songs of the search result starting at position 0. That would be your page 1. For page 2 you simply run the same query again but with `LIMIT 10,10`.

Using this you can create your <kbd>Previous</kbd> and <kbd>Next</kbd> buttons:

**HTML**

```
<a href="search.php?query=pop&page=1">Previous</a>
<a href="search.php?query=pop&page=3">Next</a>
```

**PHP**

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * 10;
$query = "SELECT name, artist, ... FROM songs WHERE genre = 'pop' LIMIT $start,10";
```

Comment: But he want to do that using Ajax maybe you should add How to change it to ajax way using json for example.

Comment: Thanks.That covers 50% of the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The technique is called pagination. Here's a PHP helper class that can help you with pagination:

```
<?php

// This is a helper class to make paginating 
// records easy.
class Pagination {

  public $current_page;
  public $per_page;
  public $total_count;

  public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=20, $total_count=0){
    $this->current_page = (int)$page;
    $this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
    $this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
  }

  public function offset() {
    // Assuming 20 items per page:
    // page 1 has an offset of 0    (1-1) * 20
    // page 2 has an offset of 20   (2-1) * 20
    //   in other words, page 2 starts with item 21
    return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
  }

  public function total_pages() {
    return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
    }

  public function previous_page() {
    return $this->current_page - 1;
  }

  public function next_page() {
    return $this->current_page + 1;
  }

    public function has_previous_page() {
        return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
    }

    public function has_next_page() {
        return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
    }


}

?>
```

### USE IN CONSTRUCTING THE SQL

```
$total_count = $db->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM songs" );
$per_page = 10;
$current_page = $page;
$pagination = new Pagination($current_page, $per_page, $total_count);
$all = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$per_page} OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}");
```